# Spatial arrangement similarity comparison that is reliant on class?

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, spatial, similarity

I have two dictionaries with coordinates and class key-value pairs and I would like to compare them. Each coordinate is attached to a specific class (either red or green). I am trying to calculate the similarity between the spatial arrangements, taking class into consideration.

For example, I would like to find the similarity of the coordinates on the right to the ones on the left:

[image: click for image]

My idea to approach this would be to find the nearest neighbors of each coordinate and check how well they match up to a coordinate with similar nearest neighbors. But the issue I see with this is finding which coordinate corresponds to the coordinate in the other image.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: An observation: In this particular configuration, sweeping a line left to right, or right to left, produces each item of each class in the same order, for each drawing; you can therefore map the coordinates each class of items in one drawing to their counterpart in the other. Not sure how that generalizes.

Comment: You can use the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) for the matching problem.